# Unity2D: Enemy ignoring collision when moving back down

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision

My game is a 2D top down platform, I have an zombie enemy that moves up and down the stage, I can place obstacles (such as a create) in its way to stop the enemy, the enemy has the ability to dodge these obstacles at any random moment. If the enemy collided with the create, the enemy will stop its movement to break the create. Once the create is broken, the enemy will continue to moving up, hit point B and then will move back down the stage. My Problem: If the enemy were to dodge left (for example) and then continues to move down and passes another create, the enemy will ignore collision and the function for it to stop and break that create. How do I fix this issue?

```
public bool hitCollider = false;
public bool hitCollider2 = false;
public bool canMove = true;
public bool moveDown = false;
public bool isMovingUp = true;
public bool isMovingDown = false;
public bool isSomethere = false;
public bool ifMoving;

public float velocidadMax;

public float xMax;
public float xMin;
public float delay;

public float x;
private float tiempo;
public float countDown, countUp, startTime;

void Start () {
    Bcol = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D> ();
    Bcol.isTrigger = true;
    isMovingUp = true;
    rigid = GetComponent <Rigidbody2D> ();
    velocidadMax = 0.12f;
    x = velocidadMax;
    InvokeRepeating ("turnFalse", startTime, countDown); // changing lanes
    InvokeRepeating ("turnTrue", 0, countUp); // moving up or down 
    ifMoving = true;
    movedownSpeed = -4f;
    moveupSpeed = 4f;
    hascollidedwHouse = false;
}

void Update () {

    if (moveDown == false) {
        rigid.velocity = new Vector2 (0, moveupSpeed); // moving up
        if (ifMoving == true) {

            //irrelevant - don't need to know code here! 

        } else if (ifMoving == false) {
            movedownSpeed = -4;
            moveupSpeed = 0;
            Move ();
        }

    }

    if (moveDown == true) {
        if (hitMascot2 == true) {

        } else if (hitMascot2 == false) {
            movingDown = true;
            Bcol.isTrigger = true;

            StartCoroutine (waitMove ());
            StartCoroutine (destroyObj ()); 
        }
    }

    if (isMovingDown == true) {
        Debug.Log ("MovingDown");
        Bcol.isTrigger = true;

        if (canMove == false) {
            Debug.Log ("is False" + canMove);  
            moveupSpeed = 4f;
        } 

        hitCollider = false;
        hitCollider2 = false;
    }

if (hitCollider == true) {
        StartCoroutine (wait ());
        Debug.Log ("I HAVE COLLIDED");
        if (canMove == true) {
            movedownSpeed = 0f;
        }
        if (canMove == false) {
            movedownSpeed = -4f;
        }
        moveupSpeed = 0f;
    }

    if (hitCollider2 == true) {
        StartCoroutine (wait2 ());
        Debug.Log ("I HAVE COLLIDED");
        if (canMove == true) {
            movedownSpeed = 0f;
        }
        if (canMove == false) {
            movedownSpeed = -4f;
        }
        moveupSpeed = 0f;
    }
}


void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D col) {

    if (col.tag == "objects") {
        hitCollider = true;
        woodBox = true;
        canMove = false;
        moveDown = false;
        xMax = 0;
        xMin = 0;
        if (hascollidedwHouse == true) {
            moveDown = false;
            isMovingDown = false;
            movedownSpeed = 0;
            moveupSpeed = 0;
            hitCollider = false;
            ifMoving = false;
            xMax = 0;
            xMin = 0;
            StartCoroutine (waitDown ());
        }
    }

    if (col.tag == "objects2") {
        hitCollider2 = true;
        metalBox = true;
        canMove = false;
        hitwoodenC = false;
        hitmetalC = true;
        moveDown = false;
        xMax = 0;
        xMin = 0;
        if (hascollidedwHouse == true) {
            moveDown = false;
            isMovingDown = false;
            movedownSpeed = 0;
            moveupSpeed = 0;
            ifMoving = false;
            hitCollider2 = false;
            xMax = 0;
            xMin = 0;
            StartCoroutine (waitDown2 ());
        }
    }

    if (col.tag == "pointB") {
        if (ifMoving == false) {
            moveupSpeed = 0;
            movedownSpeed = -4;

        } else if (ifMoving == true) {
            moveupSpeed = 0;
            movedownSpeed = -4;

        }
        Debug.Log ("Collided");
        moveDown = true;
        isMovingDown = true;
        isMovingUp = false;
        canMove = false;
        hascollidedwHouse = true;
}

void Move () {
    if (isSomethere == false) {
        if (isMovingUp == true) {
            tiempo += Time.deltaTime;
            if (transform.localPosition.x < xMin) {
                x = Random.Range (0.0f, velocidadMax);
                x = velocidadMax;
                tiempo = 0.0f; 
                Debug.Log ("Left");
            }
            if (tiempo > 1.0f) { //1.0   0.3
                x = -velocidadMax;
                tiempo = 0.0f;
                Debug.Log ("Right");
            }
            transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (transform.localPosition.x + x, transform.localPosition.y);
        }
    } else if (isSomethere == true) {
        movedownSpeed = -4;
        moveupSpeed = 4;
        if (iSPdeath == true) {
            movedownSpeed = 0;
            moveupSpeed = 0;
        }
    }
}

void turnFalse ()
{
    if( hitCollider == false) {
        ifMoving = false; // moves left and right
    }

    if( hitCollider2 == false) {
        ifMoving = false; // moves left and right
    }
}
void turnTrue() {
    if( hitCollider == false) {
        ifMoving = true; // moves up and down
    }

    if( hitCollider2 == false) {
        ifMoving = true; // moves up and down
    }
}


IEnumerator wait() {

    yield return new WaitForSeconds (2.5f);
    hitCollider = false; 

    if (isMovingUp == true) {
        canMove = true;
    } 

    if (isMovingUp == false) {
        canMove = false;
        moveupSpeed = 0f;
        movedownSpeed = -4f;

    } 

    if (canMove == true) {
        moveupSpeed = 4f;
    }
}

IEnumerator wait2() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (5.2f);
    hitCollider = false; 
    if (isMovingUp == true) {
        canMove = true;
    } 

    if (isMovingUp == false) {
        canMove = false;
        moveupSpeed = 0f;
        movedownSpeed = -4f;

    } 

    if (canMove == true) {
        moveupSpeed = 4f;
    }
}

IEnumerator waitDown() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (2.5f);
    movedownSpeed = -4f;
    moveupSpeed = 0f;
    moveDown = true;
}

IEnumerator waitDown2() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (5.2f);
    movedownSpeed = -4f;
    moveupSpeed = 0f;
    moveDown = true;
}
```

}

Comment: I cannot say for sure since your issue seems rather cloudy. But since the 'zombie' is moving after breaking a crate and you do not use OnTriggerExit2D I assume you never reset the variable 'hitCollider' which could result in the 'zombie' to ignore future collisions.

Comment: Yeah, I've been looking and testing the variable 'hitCollider' by setting it to either true or false to see if that fixes my problems but noting was happening, the zombies still continue to ignore future collisions.